# simplifying a 'fraction' mod $p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I came across this step in a proof:

$$\sum_{n} \frac{1}{n(p-n)} \equiv - \sum_{n} \frac{1}{n^2} \mod p$$

$\frac{1}{n(p-n)} = \frac{1}{np-n^2}$, and since we're considering mod $p$ I'm assuming that $np$ got divided out? How does that exactly work since we're dealing with fractions of integers mod $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point here is just that $p = 0\text{ mod } p$ so that
$\frac{1}{n(p-n)} = \frac{1}{n(0-n)} = -\frac{1}{n^2}$ mod $p$. Or in your words, $np = 0\text{ mod } p$ so that the fraction is just $\frac{1}{-n^2}$. My only concern is the indexing of this summation. You don't specify whether $n$ is running over all integers or what. And...in the cases where $p | n$ we have a problem of dividing by 0 potentially...

Answer (score 0):

We are in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, which is a field.

If $a\neq 0$ then $ a \equiv b ~\text{mod}p \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{a}\equiv\dfrac{1}{b} ~\text{mod} p$.

And now, since  $n(p-n) =np-n^2 \equiv-n^2 ~\text{mod}p$ we conclude.